# How to simulate DEL key press on CKEditor from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, ckeditor

**Short story:**

```
// get the editor instance
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

// this is what I want, but it does not exist
editor.execCommand('delete');

// I've played with this, found somewhere, but without success.
editor.fire('key', { keyCode : 46 } )
```

**Long story:**

there is a problem when using the CKEditor within the Webbrowser control from .NET WindowsForms. Several keys, including the DELete key are not propagated to the control at all.

I managed to intercept the key using a global keyboard hook and sent window messages direct to the embedded IE window handle, but without success.

Now my goal is to simulate the delete key from within the javascript, because I can call a js function from my .NET app.
Somehow this must work, because it works within the virtual keyboard plugin.
(see [sample](http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/richedit/ckeditor/plugins/Jsvk/examples/sample.html))

Sadly I wasn't able to get how this works from the plugin code.
I would be glad if anybody can post a working sample.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library used in javascript virtual keyboard ([Jsvk plugin](http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/richedit/ckeditor/plugins/Jsvk/examples/sample.html)).
It is called DocumentSelection and can be found [here](http://svn.debugger.ru/repos/jslibs/BrowserExtensions/tags/BrowserExtensions.023/documentselection.js).

```
<script src="./documentselection.js"></script>

function simulateDelete()
{
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    var container = (editor.container.getElementsByTag('textarea').getItem(0) ||
                     editor.container.getElementsByTag('iframe').getItem(0)
                    ).$;
    DocumentSelection.deleteAtCursor(container, true);
}
```

Maybe someone has an easier solution without the need of an external libaray.

Answer (score 0):

I think u want some clues...

There it is...Check the Documentation

[Key Event in CKEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.event.html#$)

```
alert( event.getKey() );
```

to get the key Element and also the other one is

```
alert( event.getKeystroke() == 65 );// "a" key
alert( event.getKeystroke() == CKEDITOR.CTRL + 65 );// CTRL + "a" key
alert( event.getKeystroke() == CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 65 );//CTRL + SHIFT + "a" key
```